# How to set style if the content is X

Tags: css

I have a

```
 <span class="go"> 100,0 </span>
 <span class="go"> 0,0 </span>
```

And want to format this span as ITALIC **only when the value is 0,0** using CSS.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Madara Uchiha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) already mentioned, this is not possible using only CSS.

But you could use a data attribute like `<span class="go" data-value="0,0"> 0,0 </span>` and query it in CSS with the attribute selector: `[data-value="0,0"] { ... }` (assuming you have access to the markup).

Comment: Rudolph, it's not working.... any idea? .peso[data-value="0,0"] {
 font-style: italic;
}

Comment: You don't mention the "peso" class in your original post. Are you sure you have that class applied to the `span`s?

Comment: sorry! wrong class name!!!! now it's working perfect!